# Firebase Cloud Functions - "not defined" error for npm dependency & including a module with client side code

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing an app with **Firebase** and I'm using **Cloud Functions** to generate a QR code, among other things.

I have **two problems**:

**1,** I'm trying to use the [qrcodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcodejs) npm package in Cloud Functions.
I ran `sudo npm install --save qrcodejs` in my `functions` directory.

This is the relevant part of the `package.js` file in the `functions` directory:

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.8.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1",
    "kjua": "^0.1.2",
    "qrcodejs": "^1.0.0"
  },
```

When the code is deployed and runs, I get a **'QRCode is not defined'** error in the **Cloud Functions log**.

This is my **functions/index.js** file:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var qrcodejs = require('qrcodejs')

exports.events = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  const eventID = req.path
  const promise = admin.database()
  .ref('events' + eventID)
  .once('value')

  return promise.then(result => {

    var qrcode = new QRCode("test", {
      text: "http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie",
      width: 128,
      height: 128,
      colorDark : "#000000",
      colorLight : "#ffffff",
      correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
    });

    var html = `
    <!doctype html>
      <head>
        <title>${result.val().title}</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        ${qrcode}</br>
        ${result.val().title}
      </body>
    </html>`

    return res.status(200).send(html);
  });
});
```

**The error points to this line:** `var qrcode = new QRCode("test", {`.
I'm pretty sure I'm doing the insertion into the html string wrong as well, but the error points to the line above.

**2,** I've tried using another qr code npm package too, [kjua](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kjua). I'd much prefer to use **kjua**, but I'm having an additional problem with that.

Upon running `firebase deploy` I get the following error at the '`i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...`' step:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

It points to the second line of the `functions/node_modules/kjua/dist/kjua.min.js` file.

The problem seems to be that the code is written as it were run in a browser. Can I still include this package as a dependency in Cloud Functions somehow?

Thank you very much

Comment: That qrcodejs library says it's for browsers, not node.js. Maybe that's the problem.  "IE6~10, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Mobile Safari, Android, Windows Mobile, ETC."

Comment: @DougStevenson Seems like you are right! I found a QR code generator package for node.js and it's working! https://github.com/soldair/node-qrcode

Thank you so much! I'm new to JS and don't yet understand what node.js is.

Answer (score 0):

For sake of Answer, for people like me you just need to replace

`window` with `global` and it works in node.js / cloud functions.